# Not able attach csv file while sending automated mail

Tags: r

Below is the line I am using to attach a csv while sending automated mail from R. But I get only mail and not the attachement

```
file = "File.csv"
add_attachment(email, file , content_type = mime::guess_type(file))
```

Can anyone help me

Comment: This is a hack around the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63443758/8280329

Answer (score 0):

With "file", you are just providing a name to the attachment, you should be using "filename" for the actual attachment.

Please refer:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/blastula/versions/0.3.1/topics/add_attachment

Comment: Have you given entire file path? Also, mailR is a preferable package to be used (according to me).

Comment: No it is actually only the file name and not the filep path

Comment: If sending from R, how could it be .csv file without any path? Something is wrong.

Comment: Sorry. Can u please explain. What is wrong. What is path then?