# add_attachment in blastula R package

Tags: r, r-markdown, blastula

How can I sent an attachment in blastula.

```
correo <- compose_email(
  body = md("Tarea_01"))
```

```
correo %>% add_attachment(file = "emilia/tarea_01/liquenes.csv", filename = "liquenes")
```

```
correo %>%
  smtp_send(
    from = "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
    to = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    subject = "Tarea_01",
    credentials = creds_key(id = "gmail")
  )
```

I can send the email but there is no attachment in received email.

Any clue why there is no attachment?

Manuel

Answer (score 4):

Just stumbled over this older question - I believe the problem is in in your second code block

`correo %>% add_attachment(file = "emilia/tarea_01/liquenes.csv", filename = "liquenes")`

is actually not changing correo, you have to reassign it or directly proceed with the pipe, e.g.

```
correo %>% 
  add_attachment(file = "emilia/tarea_01/liquenes.csv", filename = "liquenes") %>%
  smtp_send(
    from = "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
    to = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    subject = "Tarea_01",
    credentials = creds_key(id = "gmail")
  )
```

With this setup I don´t have problems with attaching something.

Answer (score 0):

The add_attachments() function didn't work for me.  I "de-functionized" it and could get it to send an attachment.

```
file = paste0(source_path, "current.html")
content_type = mime::guess_type(file)
filename = basename(file)

expanded_path <- file %>% path.expand() %>% normalizePath(mustWork = TRUE)
attachment_list <- list(file_path = expanded_path, content_type = content_type, 
                    disposition = "attachment", filename = filename)
email$attachments <- c(email$attachments, list(attachment_list))
```

Where "file" is the complete path to the attachment.  Took code directly out of function and it worked.  Could not figure out why function wouldn't.